# There is a problem when I use indentation in Python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

```
def greet(name):
    """
    This function greets to
    the person passed in as
    a parameter
    """
    print("Hello, " + name + ". Good morning!")
```

This is a basic example for defining a function, and when I run this code on Python 3.8.5 by VSC, the result is like below.

```
>>> def greet(name):
... 
  File "<stdin>", line 2
    
    ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

It says that there is an indentation error but I really don't know why. And also, line 2 is not just blank but according to the result, line 2 seems like blank.

```
for number in range(5):
    print("Thank you")
```

```
>>> for number in range(5):
... 
  File "<stdin>", line 2
    
    ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

Same error for 'for'. Can anyone help?

Comment: What is your IDE/text editor? Try opening the file in a raw text editor.

Comment: @JoshuaF The question says the problem is in VSC == Visual Studio Code

Comment: The `>>>` suggests that you may be using the Python REPL and perhaps pasting this code in. How are you trying to run the Python script? See [Getting Started with Python in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial).

Comment: @jarmod I entered the code on editor and run in terminal by press 'Shift + Enter' line by line

Comment: `print(f"Hello, { name }. Good morning!")` or `print("Hello, {}. Good morning!".format(name))`

Answer (score 0):

Right now, you are running the Python script line-by-line by placing the VS Code cursor on each line of code and then pressing shift+enter. This utilizes the Python Interactive window afaik. It works fine for running individual lines but if you want to run a collection of lines that include indentation e.g. a for loop or function definition, then select *all* of those lines together and then press shift+enter. You would need to do this for code that's indented, for example:

```
def greet(name):
    print("Hello, " + name + ". Good morning!")
```

Alternatively, if you have read [Getting Started with Python in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial) and specifically installed the [Python extension for VS Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python) then you will be able to click the `Run Python File in Terminal` button (it looks like a Play icon) to run your Python script.

[image]

Alternatively, you can launch a [Terminal Window](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal) in VS Code and manually run the Python script using `python3 hello.py` (or potentially `python hello.py`, depending on your Python installation).

Comment: @GuKim you're encouraged to upvote and accept this as the answer, if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

You should not press `Shift+Enter` to run the code in the terminal **line by line**.

Because the REPL will add an `Enter` to start a new line automatically like this:

[image]

You can select all of the codes then send them to the REPL:

[image]